# How do i check how long a file has been in the Recycle Bin?

Tags: windows, windows-7, recycle-bin

As a test i wrote a .NET script which recursively looks in `C:\$Recycle.Bin` and i'd like to delete files after they been in there for X days.

I decided to check the access time but access time isn't updated on move. How do i check if a file has been in there for X period of time? (i'm using windows 7)

Comment: You [ask for the `System.Recycle.DateDeleted` extended property](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/08/30/10202076.aspx). Once you decide which items you want to delete, [you can invoke the delete verb](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/01/10204404.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This c# version may help:

```
var Shl = new Shell(); Folder Recycler = Shl.NameSpace(10); 
FI = Recycler.Items().Item(0);   
string FileName = Recycler.GetDetailsOf(FI, 0); 
string FilePath = Recycler.GetDetailsOf(FI, 1); 
string RecyleDate = Recycler.GetDetailsOf(FI, 2);
```